# How to determine which triangle in a model is at screen coordinate x,y?

Tags: opengl-es

Developing for OpenGL ES, so no access to glut or glu.

I'm wondering what the best way to determine which triangle falls under a screen point at (x,y) is.

Comment: Which triangle closest to the camera?  What if that screen point coincides with a vertex of multiple triangles?

Comment: In that case, assuming this a picking application, you return an arbitrary one. Same answer for hitting an edge. It might be user friendly if the arbitrary choice cycled in some nice way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for "picking".

Comment: Thanks, that immensely improves my googling results.

Comment: There's nothing quite like knowing the "right" term of art for improving search results.

Comment: Yes. Definitely. I've already solved my problem. What did that take? Less than an hour?

 Once again thanks.